# Выбрать элементы массива у которых индекс начинается с field_

Tags: php

Добрых суток! У  меня есть массив

```
$page = array(
   'title' => 'page1',
   'text' => 'hello world',
   'field_image' => 'img/site/ie.png',
   'field_icq' => '44234324',
   'field_rabota' => 'Требуется'
);
```

Мне нужно из этого массива выбрать все элементы, в которых индекс начинается со слова field_ , создать другой массив и вставить эти элементы туда. К концу рабочего дня свои наработки показать не могу, очень хотелось бы увидеть именно эффективное решение этой задачи. Заранее очень благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$page = array(
   'title' => 'page1',
   'text' => 'hello world',
   'field_image' => 'img/site/ie.png',
   'field_icq' => '44234324',
   'field_rabota' => 'Требуется'
);
$new_arr = array();
foreach($page as $key => $val){
    if(preg_match('/^field_/',$key)){
        $new_arr[$key] = $val; 
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [field_image] => img/site/ie.png
    [field_icq] => 44234324
    [field_rabota] => Требуется
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_field = array_filter($page, function($key) {
    return !strncmp($key, "field_", 6);   
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: для версий ниже 5.6 опция ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY не работает, но можно обменять ключи со значениями (array_flip) до и после фильтра